# Wrong legend wehen using matplotlib and kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I created a GUI using kivy to plot data with a variety of different settings. It all worked quite well, but the legend is not shown completely. The label is shown correctly, but the line is missing, so one cannot see which line corresponds to which data set.
The odd thing is, that I have a plot function, that creates a bar plot with the very same legend which works. Somehow the code shown here does have this strange problem...

The relevant code pieces are:

header:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy import FigureCanvas
```

plot function:

```
def plot(self):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()        
    ax  = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    ax.set_title(method)
    ax.plot(x,y1, color=cmap(0),  linewidth=3,label= r"$y_{1}$")     
    ax.plot(x,y2, color=cmap(256),linewidth=3,label= r"$y_{2}$")
    ax.plot(x,y3, color=cmap(128),linewidth=3,label= r"$y_{3}$")
    ax.set_ylim([0,25])
    plt.legend()
    return fig
```

calling of the plot function:

```
def draw_canvas(self,**kwargs):
    #initialize root widget
    super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.plot()
```

calling of draw_canwas:

```
def btn_pressed(self, instance):
    ...some code...
    self.clear_widgets()
    self.draw_canvas()
```

Note, that I did not define variables the code pieces. They are defined in the complete code. The plot itself works fine...

Comment: Have you accidentally missed off the name of your plot function?

Comment: See [mcve]. Only if people can reproduce the issue they are likely to come up with a solution.

Comment: @DavidG Yes....